# Funny styling behaviour in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx, create-react-app

So I'm trying to learn React.js by building a simple todo list application, but for some reason I get some funny behaviour when I declare the styling of a `<td>` as an object. Here's my code of the TodoListItem.js file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class TodoListItem extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      isEditing: false
    }
  }


  onEditClick() {
    if(this.isEditing) {
      this.setState({ isEditing: false})
    }
    else {
      this.setState({isEditing: true})
    }
  }

  renderActionSection() {
    if (!this.state.isEditing) {
      return (
        <td>
          <div className="btn-group" role="group">
            <button onClick={this.onEditClick.bind(this)} className="btn btn-default">Edit</button>
            <button className="btn btn-danger" >Delete</button>
          </div>
        </td>
      )
    } else {
      return (
        <td>
          <div className="btn-group" role="group">
            <button onClick={this.onSaveClick.bind(this)} className="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            <button className="btn btn-danger" >Delete</button>
          </div>
        </td>
      )
    }
  }

  renderTaskSection() {
    const {task, isCompleted} = this.props

    console.log(task + ' ' +isCompleted)

    const taskStyle = {
      color: isCompleted ? 'green' : 'red',
      cursor: 'pointer'
    }

    return(
      <td style={taskStyle}>{task}</td>
    )
  }

  onSaveClick() {
    this.setState({isEditing: false})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <tr>
          {this.renderTaskSection()}
          {this.renderActionSection()}
      </tr>
    )
  }
}
```

Each element has both a key and an action value, but when I change the styling of the ActionSection by creating a `const` and assigning its value to a `<td>`:

```
const taskStyle = {
      color: isCompleted ? 'green' : 'red',
      cursor: 'pointer'
    }

    return(
      <td style={taskStyle}>{task}</td>
    )
```

The `<td>` is always either green or red, depending on which value I put before the other in the ternary statement.

Do you know what's happening? How could I fix this?

EDIT:
Upon closer inspection, it seems that the color styling only works for new elements I put in the list, which I used as a workaround for solving the problem by not putting any TODOS in the list beforehand.

Comment: Did you check your `isCompleted` variable.  Does it changes value and is not `null`  or `undefined` ?

Comment: How are you using the TodoListItem component?  Are you passing in the isCompleted prop as a boolean?  Are you providing the prop everytime?

Comment: @anuragasaurus Yes, I have console.logged the value of isCompleted, and it returns the correct value (either true or false)

Comment: @c0deNinja I only use the isCompleted prop once to determine the color, and I am getting it with a constant with es6 syntax ({isCompleted}=this.props). It is passed in as a boolean from anobject (which is an element of an array) in the main component file

Comment: @Corrado strange indeed.

Comment: The question needs to be reworded because I don't understand the question. The 'funny behaviour' isn't explained.

Comment: You're more likely to get an answer if you post a demo. See this pen for a working example of the todo app, which you can fork and paste your code in.
https://codepen.io/kavishmehta/pen/yaxwVR

Comment: @Win yes, in the end of the question I say that the <td> is always either red or green, depending on what I put first in the conditional statement